# 12 Hour Clock (AM/PM)

Tags: java

This class ClockDisplay implements a 12 hour digital clock.

```
     public class NumberDisplay
  {
 //instance variables
 private int state;
 private int limit;

 public NumberDisplay(int rollOverLimit)
 {
    state = 0;
    setLimit(rollOverLimit);
 }

   public int getState()
 {
        return state;
 }

 public int getLimit()
 {
        return limit;
 }

    public void setState(int replacementValue)
 {
    if( replacementValue >= 0 && replacementValue < limit)
        state = replacementValue;
 }

    public void setLimit(int rollOverLimit)
 {
   // if (rollOverLimit > 0)
     //   limit = rollOverLimit;


   limit = (rollOverLimit > 0 ? rollOverLimit : limit);

   state = ( state > limit ? 0 : state);

  }//of setLimit


  public void increment()
  {
    /*
    if (state == limit-1)
        state = 0;
    else
        state++;
      */  
    state = (state+1) % limit;    
    }


   public String getDisplayValue()
    {
    if(state < 10){
        return "0" + state;
    }
    else{
        return ""+ state;
    }
  }


   }

   public class ClockDisplay {

  // instance variables
  private NumberDisplay hours;
   private NumberDisplay minutes;
   private String displayString;
   private boolean isAM;
   public String displayAMPM;

    //    private int count = 0;
    public ClockDisplay() {
    hours = new NumberDisplay(12);
    minutes = new NumberDisplay(60);
    updateDisplay();
    }

    public ClockDisplay(int hour, int minute, String displayAMPM) {

    hours = new NumberDisplay(12);
    minutes = new NumberDisplay(60);
    setTime(hour, minute, displayAMPM);
    //setMorning(isAM);
    //count = 0;
    updateDisplay();
    }

    public void timeTick() {

    minutes.increment();
    if (minutes.getState() == 0) {
        hours.increment();
    }

    if (hours.getState() == 12) {
        if (displayAMPM == "AM") {
            displayAMPM = "PM";
        } else if (displayAMPM == "PM") {
            displayAMPM = "AM";
        }
    }
    //if (isAM != isAM)
    //displayAMPM = "PM";

    updateDisplay();

    }//of timeTick

    public void setTime(int hour, int minute, String displayAMPM) {
    if (hour == 12) {
        hour = 0;
    }
    hours.setState(hour);
    minutes.setState(minute);
    updateDisplay();
    }

    public void setHours(int hour) {
    hours.setState(hour);
    updateDisplay();
    }

    public void setMinutes(int minute) {
    minutes.setState(minute);
    updateDisplay();
    }
   /*public void setMorning(boolean isAM)
     {
    isAM = true;
    displayAMPM = "AM";
     }
    public void setAfternoon(boolean isAM)
    {
    isAM = false;
    displayAMPM = "PM";
 }
 */

private void updateDisplay() {
    int hour = hours.getState();
    if (hour == 0) {
        hour = 12;
    }

    displayString = hour + ":" + minutes.getDisplayValue() + displayAMPM;

  }

public String getTime() {

    return displayString;
}
}

public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ClockDisplay clock12 = new ClockDisplay(11, 59, "AM");
    System.out.println(clock12.displayAMPM);
    System.out.println(clock12.getTime());
    while (true) {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(60000);
        clock12.timeTick();
        System.out.println(clock12.getTime());
    }
 }
}
```

The above program is 12 Hour Clock with AM/PM display
The variable displayAMPM is taken as null if I give an input "AM" or "PM"

```
Output: null
        11:59null
        12.00null
```

I am not sure whats going wrong in this program. Can anyone please help me on this ?

Comment: You should include minimal piece of code which shows the problem. Why would we need to see commented out methods?

Comment: please create a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: My guess is that `displayAMPM` is null, since you never set it unless the hour is 12.  (But the code's pretty much impossible to understand.)

Answer (score 0):

You are never changing the value of `displayAMPM` on initialization. You should do it in the constructor, in this case, in the method you are calling:

```
public void setTime(int hour, int minute, String displayAMPM) {
    if (hour == 12) {
        hour = 0;
    }
    hours.setState(hour);
    minutes.setState(minute);
    this.displayAMPM = displayAMPM; // 'this.displayAPMP' will refer 
                                    // to the instance attribute 'displayAMPM'
    updateDisplay();
}
```

Also, don't use `==` operator to compare strings. Since they are objects and you want to compare its contents (not its references) you should use `.equals()`.

Comment: Thank you Christian for the reply.
 
I have taken care of String.equals().
I have intialised displayAMPM in setTime method.

But Still unable to change AM to PM.

Output:
AM
11:59AM
12:00AM


Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the correct result from `hours.getState()`? Are you sure you are using the method `equals()` correctly?: `displayAMPM.equals("AM")`

Comment: Also note that on each *tick*, `displayAMPM` will be checked, so it will change on every minute. To fix this you can include the AMPM-check-part *inside* the `if (minutes.getState() == 0)`

Comment: I think something is going wrong with hours.getState(). It is returning Zero. displayAMPM.equals("AM") is the same condition I have written.

Comment: I have placed my other class from which I am extracting the hours. Can you please look into it ?

Comment: I would recommend to create another question for this. But please be sure to follow the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) recommendations so you ask a good question! Also, if this answer solved the first problem you posted about, mark it as accepted.

Comment: Oddly, using `==` for comparing to the literal strings "AM" and "PM" will work, since those strings are interned and will only ever have one instance.  (But in the general case it's going to be a bug, and it's best to use `equals` all the time to get in the habit of doing it right.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not have set displayAMPM string when constructor is get called.

As per my opinion you have to initialize that string when you called constructor otherwise it will not set as in hours.getState() == "12" you have checked previous value that is never set so it will not set to any value.

Hope this suggestion help you.